# Why is the feasible set of solutions to an SDP a spectrahedron?

Tags: convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming, spectrahedra

> A spectrahedron is the set $$ S = \left\lbrace (x_1,\cdots,x_m)\in \mathbb{R}^m \quad|\quad A_0+ A_ix_i \succeq 0 \quad i\in [m] \right\rbrace$$
>
> for some given symmetric matrices $A_0, A_1,\cdots, A_m$. An SDP problem is 
>   \begin{align*}
> \text{minimize }& \langle C,X\rangle \\
> \langle A_i,X \rangle &= b_i \;\; i=\{1,\cdots m\} \\
> X &\succeq 0
> \end{align*}
>   where $C,A_i$ are symmetric and $\langle A,X \rangle= Tr(A^TX)=\sum_{ij}A_{ij}X_{ij}$.

How do I see the feasible set of X as in the condition given in the definition of $S$?

Comment: Where did you get this? This is confusingly constructed. The problem is that there are a couple of ways people typically describe SDPs that are duals of each other. The spectrahedron definition is using one of those definitions, and the "SDP problem" is using the other. In effect, they're talking about two different sets of $A$ matrices.

Answer (score 3):

The definition of spectrahedron that you've given simply isn't one of the standard definitions of a spectrahedron.  The two commonly used definitions are

1. A spectrahedron is a set of matrices in $S^{n}$ (symmetric $n$ by $n$ matrices) such that

$\mbox{tr} (A_{i}X)=b_{i}\;\; i=1, 2, \ldots, m$

$X \succeq 0$.

The feasible set of your SDP is a spectrahedron under this definition.

2. A spectrahedron is a set of vectors $x \in R^{k}$ such that

$A_{0} + \sum_{i=1}^{k} x_{i}A_{i} \succeq 0$

(Note that there is only one $\succeq$ inequality here rather than $m$ as given in the question, but there is a sum of $x_{i}A_{i}$ terms lacking in the definition given in the question.)

An important point is that the Lagrangian dual of the SDP based on definition 1 is an optimization problem over a definition 2 spectrahedron.

Since the second definition says that the spectrahedron is a set of vectors in $R^{k}$ and the first says that the spectrahedron is a set of matrices in $S^{n}$, they clearly aren't exactly the same.   However,
it turns out that these two definitions are essentially equivalent in that any spectrahedron under definition 1 is related to a definition 2 spectrahedron as shown by the following construction.

To find a definition 2 spectrahedron from a definition 1 spectrahedron,

1. Find a symmetric matrix $B_{0}$ such that

$\mbox{tr}(A_{i}B_{0})=b_{i}\;\; i=1, 2, \ldots, m$

If no such matrix exists, then the original SDP is infeasible and the spectrahedron is the empty set.

2. Find a basis (of symmetric matrices) for the null space of the linear system of equations

$V=\left\{ X\in S^{n} |\; \mbox{tr}(A_{i}X)=0 \;\; i=1, 2, \ldots, m \right\}$

Call this basis $B_{1}$, $B_{2}$, $\ldots$, $B_{k}$

3. Then

$\left\{ X \in S^{n} |\; \mbox{tr}(A_{i}X)=b_{i}\;\; i=1, 2, \ldots, m,\; X \succeq 0 \right\}= \left\{B \in S^{n} | B=B_{0}+x_{1}B_{1}+\ldots +x_{k}B_{k},\; B \succeq 0 \right\}$.

The set on the right is a set of matrices in $S^{n}$ rather than a definition 2 spectrahedron, but the coefficients $x_{i}$ are the elements of a definition 2 spectrahedron with matrices $B_{0}$, $B_{1}$, $\ldots$, $B_{k}$.

This construction is sometimes useful in modeling with semidefinite programming.  If you have a very highly constrained SDP problem, then it can sometimes be useful to switch from the definition 1 spectrahedral constraints to definition 2 spectrahedral constraints.